# Appointment form - strange stucture after error message

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with the appointment form. When the form is filled in by the customer, but a required field is left blank, this field will get an error message. This works fine. The problem is that the different choice menu's on this page get a strange structure then. With this problem the wrong date will be sent. If you want you can test the form here; [http://www.o-vita.nl/afspraak.php](http://o-vita.nl/afspraak.php).

The Form:

```
          <form action="afspraak_verstuur.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                <table width="300" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Naam*:</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                                                          <select name="aanhef" type="text" class="text_aanhef" value="Selecteer uw aanhef" />
                     <option value="Aanhef">Aanhef</option>
                    <option value="Mevr.">Mevr.</option>
                    <option value="Dhr.">Dhr.</option>

                    </select>
    <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['aanhef'])) ? $_SESSION['aanhef'] : ""; ?>
                                <input name="name" type="text" class="text_naam" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['name'])) ? $_SESSION['name'] : ""; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if (in_array('name', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen naam ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">E-mail*:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="email" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['email'])) ? $_SESSION['email'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('email', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen e-mailadres ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Adres:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="adres" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['adres'])) ? $_SESSION['adres'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('adres', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen adres ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


                                <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Postcode:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="postcode" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['postcode'])) ? $_SESSION['postcode'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('postcode', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen postcode ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


            <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Woonplaats:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="woonplaats" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['woonplaats'])) ? $_SESSION['woonplaats'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('woonplaats', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen woonplaats ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Telefoon*:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="telefoon" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['telefoon'])) ? $_SESSION['telefoon'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('telefoon', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen telefoonnummer ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>

            <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Datum*:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <select name="dag" type="text" class="text_dag" value="Selecteer een dag" />
                    <option value="maandag">maandag</option>
                    <option value="dinsdag">dinsdag</option>
                    <option value="woensdag">woensdag</option>
                    <option value="donderdag">donderdag</option>
                    <option value="vrijdag">vrijdag</option>
                    <option value="zaterdag">zaterdag</option>
                    </select>
    <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['dag'])) ? $_SESSION['dag'] : ""; ?>

                    <select name="dag_nummer" type="text" class="text_dag_nummer" value="1" />
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option> 
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option> 
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
    <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['dag_nummer'])) ? $_SESSION['dag_nummer'] : ""; ?>

                    <select name="maand" type="text" class="text_maand" value="Januari" />
                    <option value="januari">januari</option>
                    <option value="februari">februari</option>
                    <option value="maart">maart</option>
                    <option value="april">april</option>
                    <option value="mei">mei</option>
                    <option value="juni">juni</option>
                    <option value="juli">juli</option>
                    <option value="augustus">augustus</option>
                    <option value="september">september</option>
                    <option value="oktober">oktober</option>
                    <option value="november">november</option>
                    <option value="december">december</option>
                    </select>
      <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['maand'])) ? $_SESSION['maand'] : ""; ?>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('datum', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen datum ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


            <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Tijd*:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="tijd" type="text" class="text_veld" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['tijd'])) ? $_SESSION['tijd'] : ""; ?>" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('tijd', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen tijd ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>


            <tr>
                        <td class="tabform">Opmerking:</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td height="60" colspan="2">
                                        <textarea name="opmerking" type="text" class="text_comments" rows="4" value="" /><?php echo (isset($_SESSION['opmerking'])) ? $_SESSION['opmerking'] : ""; ?></textarea>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if (in_array('opmerking', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                                <font color="red">Er is geen opmerking ingevuld</font>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                                    <tr>
            <td class="tabform">
                Nieuwsbrief ontvangen?
                  <br /><input name="newsletter" type="radio" id="news_true" value="Ja" checked="checked" /> 
                <label for="news_true">Ja</label>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="news_false" value="Nee" />
                <label for="news_false">Nee</label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php if (in_array('name', $_GET['error'])) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Er is geen nieuwsbrief vermelding ingevuld
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>


                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="verzenden">
                                        <input name="verzenden" type="image" id="verzenden" src="img/verzenden.png" alt="Verzenden" title="Verzenden" />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
        </form>
```

Here is the script to send the mail:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();


if ("post" === strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {

    $aanhef = $_POST['aanhef'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $adres = $_POST['adres'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
    $telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
    $dag = $_POST['dag'];
    $dag_nummer = $_POST['dag_nummer'];
    $maand = $_POST['maand'];
    $tijd = $_POST['tijd'];
    $opmerking = $_POST['opmerking'];
    $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];

    $_SESSION['aanhef'] = $aanhef;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['adres'] = $adres;
    $_SESSION['postcode'] = $postcode;
    $_SESSION['woonplaats'] = $woonplaats;
    $_SESSION['telefoon'] = $telefoon;
    $_SESSION['dag'] = $dag;
    $_SESSION['dag_nummer'] = $dag_nummer;
    $_SESSION['maand'] = $maand;
    $_SESSION['tijd'] = $tijd;
    $_SESSION['opmerking'] = $opmerking;
    $_SESSION['newsletter'] = $newsletter;

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($telefoon) || empty($tijd)) {

        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = "name";
        }

        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = "email";
        }

        if (empty($telefoon)) {
            $errors[] = "telefoon";
        }

        if (empty($tijd)) {
            $errors[] = "tijd";
        }

        header("Location: afspraak.php?error[]=" .implode('&error[]=', $errors));
        exit;
} else {

// send mail if (post) parameters are correct
if (mail(
    'tim-luijten@hotmail.com', 
    'Afsprakenformulier o-vita.nl', 
    "Er is contact opgenomen via het afsprakenformulier. Zie onderstaande gegevens: \n\n
    Naam: {$aanhef} {$name} \n
    E-mailadres: {$email} \n
    Adres: {$adres} \n
    Postcode: {$postcode} \n
    Woonplaats: {$woonplaats} \n
    Telefoonnummer: {$telefoon} \n
    Datum: {$dag} {$dag_nummer} {$maand} \n
    Tijd: {$tijd} \n
    Opmerking: {$opmerking} \n
    Nieuwsbrief ontvangen: {$newsletter} \n"         
                ,
    "From: {$email} \r\n"
  ))
 {
     $_SESSION['aanhef'] = "";
     $_SESSION['name'] = "";
     $_SESSION['email'] = "";
     $_SESSION['adres'] = "";
     $_SESSION['postcode'] = "";
     $_SESSION['woonplaats'] = "";
     $_SESSION['telefoon'] = "";
     $_SESSION['dag'] = "";
     $_SESSION['dag_nummer'] = "";
     $_SESSION['maand'] = "";
     $_SESSION['tijd'] = "";
     $_SESSION['opmerking'] = "";
     $_SESSION['newsletter'] = "";

     header("Location: bedankt_afspraak.php");
        exit;
           } else {
    //display a message that the message failed to send.
   }
}

    }



header("Location: afspraak.php");

?>
```

I currently have it like this:

```
    <?php $days = array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
etc
etc
    // ...
);

echo '<select name="dag_nummer" type="text" class="text_dag_nummer">' . "\n";

foreach ($days as $value => $text) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"';

    if (isset($_POST['dag_nummer']) && $_POST['dag_nummer'] == $value) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }


    echo '>' . $text . "</option>\n";

}

echo "</select>\n";
 ?>
```

However, It still displays the selected value after the dropdown boxes, instead of the desired value being selected...
See my screenshot: http://piclair.com/data/gpjal.jpg

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue. What browser are you using?

Comment: For testing the website; firefox, safari, IE9 and chrome. The problem is only visible when an error is shown. The structure of the form changes and the wrong values will be sent to my e-mail​​.

Comment: I couldn't understand what was your problem, can you say an example here?

Comment: Well, the form should look like this; [link](http://piclair.com/jxros). But the form looks like [link](http://piclair.com/46jd1).

Comment: The above example occurs when a obliged field is left blank and "verzenden" is pressed.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your PHP/HTML. It's impossible to read, especially given the length.

Comment: I think I now understand your problem. If the page is POSTed back with errors, are you wanting the form elements to be populated with what they typed before?

Comment: I changed some things based on the answers. An example is shown at the bottom of the post. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to have the error page show the user's previously selected options for the drop-downs. This should be done using the following:

```
<option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
```

You will need to handle this selection programatically:

```
$days = array(
    1 => 1,
    // ...
);

echo '<select name="dag_nummer" type="text" class="text_dag_nummer">' . "\n";

foreach ($days as $value => $text) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"';

    if (isset($_POST['dag_number']) && $_POST['dag_number'] == $value) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }

    echo '>' . $text . "</option>\n";

}

echo "</select>\n";
```

This should replace your `echo (isset($_SESSION['dag_number'])) ...` logic.

Also note the structure of the `<select>` element that this constructs — with the `<option>` elements nested *inside* it.

Comment: I changed some things based on the answers. An example is shown at the bottom of the post. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aha, now I see what you're doing, you're POSTing to afspraak_verstuur.php, which redirects back to afspraak.php in case of an error... is there any reason you're doing that instead of just POSTing back to the same page? In any case, you can replace `$_POST` in my above answer with `$_SESSION`, but it seems you haven't removed the code to echo out the value of `$_SESSION['dag_nummer']` after the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Right after your `<select>` element named "aanhef", you have this line:

```
<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['aanhef'])) ? $_SESSION['aanhef'] : ""; ?>
```

That line is printing some additional text after the menu, which—judging by your screenshots—it looks like you don't want. Instead of printing that text *after* the menu, I think you probably want to test each `<option>` element to see if it matches the $_SESSION['aanhef'] value, and if so, append the attribute `selected="selected"` into that tag.

Note also that your `<select>` element currently has a slash just inside of the closing tag, like this: `<select />`. That slash shouldn't be there, since a `<select>` tag isn't self-closing.